# My class fileds are getting initialized may be because I have a @bean for the same class but in a different .java file

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring and annotations.
I started the application in debug mode and I found that by the time my code reaches init() method of Actuator below values got assigned to actVar1 and actVar2.

actVar1 has "abc" value

actVar2 has  "xyz" value

Note: My application is not yet started completely . I am just trying with debug point in init() method for a different purpose and I observed above thing.

My question is why those variables have assigned those values.

```
//Actuator.java 
@Component
public class Actuator {
private String actVar1;
private String actVar2;
//.. some code here
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
//my debug point is here 
//some code .....
}
//.. some code here

}
//Beancreator.java
@Component
public class BeanCreator {
//.. some code here
private String first="abc";
private field2 second ="xyz";
//.. some code here

@Bean 
public Actuator actuator() { 
Actuator actuator = new Actuator(); 
actuator.setActVar1(first); 
actuator.setActVar2(second); 
return actuatorPoller; 
} 
//.. some code here
}
```

When I change the method name under @Bean to different one ,those values are not getting assigned .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why those variables have assigned those values ?

First, after Spring creates a bean, it will call that bean 's `@PostConstruct` method.

Second , Spring will create a bean for the following cases:

- If a class is annotated by `@Component` or its [stereotype annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) such as `@Repository`, `@Service`, and `@Controller` etc , and auto-scanning feature is enable for the package containing that class , it will create a bean for it.
- If a method on `@Configuration` /`@Component` class is annotated with `@Bean` , Spring will [call that method to create a bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts).

So your example creates 2 beans in the type of `Actuator`. A is due to `@Component` on `Actuator` class while B is due to `@Bean` method on `BeanCreator.actuator()`.That 's why you see `init()` executes two times as there are two `Actuator` beans. For A , its `init()` is executed with NULL. For B, its `init()` is executed with "abc" and "xyz" simply because you set it in the `@Bean` method that creates it.

Answer (score 1):

According to Spring's official documentation methods annotated with `@Bean` will get automatically executed and I am assuming this happens at a point in time before you would like it to happen.

> To declare a bean, simply annotate a method with the @Bean annotation. When JavaConfig encounters such a method, it will execute that method and register the return value as a bean within a BeanFactory.

You can use `@DependsOn` annotation to control bean creation order:

> Spring, by default, manages beans’ lifecycle and arranges their initialization order.
>
> But, we can still customize it based on our needs. We can choose either the SmartLifeCycle interface or the @DependsOn annotation for managing initialization order.
>
> We should use this annotation for specifying bean dependencies. Spring guarantees that the defined beans will be initialized before attempting an initialization of the current bean.

Read more about the use of this annotation in this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on).